# Bootstrap Navbar links that show up even when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a navbar using Bootstrap.  I would like most of the button to collapse into a menu when on mobile but I want the main section links to always show up at the top level for easy access.

So for example, here's the non-collapsed view:

[image: Non-collapsed navbar]

I want the 'Teams' and 'Clues' buttons to remain even when collapsed.  Staff and Grid should appear under the hamburger menu that appears.  Right now I just have the 'Top Level' buttons as a `navbar-nav` inside my `navbar-header`.  When collapsed they take on the collapsed style and fill the entire width and stack.

```xml
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extra-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    Mine
                </a>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clues</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="extra-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I want the 'active' button highlighting, so if there's an easy way to get that sort of style by using a `navbar-btn` (which appears to stay at the top if it's not in a `navbar-collapsed` I'd be happy to try that.

Comment: use `navbar-brand` for Teams and Clues and keep below in `Mine` !

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this just a little bit change in `navbar-brand`.

use `navbar-brand` for **Teams and Clues** and keep below in **Mine** !

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extra-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    Mine
                </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand active" href="">Teams</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Clues</a>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="extra-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Grid</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you ...